# Can't fix the error in my .module file

Tags: php, drupal, module, drupal-7, drupal-modules

After searching the internet for a whole day, i still couldn't fix the error in my file. I hope someone here could help me...

This is the error i get:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\dagvandewebshop\sites\all\modules\webform_register\webform_register.module on line 878

This is my code:

```
($node->field_leveringswijze[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] >= 1 ?$form['leveringswijze']['#default_value'] = 'Levering op adres (thuis of op kantoor)' : $form['leveringswijze']['#default_value'] = 'Levering in een afhaalpunt' : $form['leveringswijze']['#default_value'] = 'Levering in een pakjes automaat');
```

Comment: Please post errors as text, not images

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written the code is in the right way. From your code I see that you wanted to set value to $form['leveringswijze']['#default_value'] in three cases. You can try below code.

```
$form['leveringswijze']['#default_value'] = ($node->field_leveringswijze[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] >= 1) ? 'Levering op adres (thuis of op kantoor)' : ('antoher condtion need to write here') ? 'Levering in een afhaalpunt' : 'Levering in een pakjes automaat';
```

Please let me know if you wanted to do different things.

Comment: How come that this code doesn't give an error then?   ($node->field_b_post[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 1 ? $form['b_post']['#default_value'] = 'ja' : $form['b_post']['#default_value'] = 'nee');

Comment: Seems your above code is correct. Can you please let me know exactly what you wanted to do.

Comment: i used the same code but it didn't work with 3 values?

Comment: And i was adding code because the new fields i made in a content type didn't show.

Comment: Please paste here your new code which you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code as you have used else statement two times.

```
($node->field_leveringswijze[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) >= 1 ? $form['leveringswijze']['#default_value'] = 'Levering op adres (thuis of op kantoor)' : $form['leveringswijze']['#default_value'] = 'Levering in een pakjes automaat';
```

Comment: But there are 3 things you can choose in the form